# Error Solving Definite Integral in Maple

Tags: unix, math, maple, integral, calculus

Basically I am trying to solve the following Definite Integral in Maple from Theta=0 to Theta0=45. I am trying to find an actual numerical value but need to find the integral first. I don't know how to ask Maple to help me solve an integral where there are two different values (theta and theta0) within. All I am trying to do is find the period of oscillation of a pendulum but I have been instructed to only use this method and equation.

From the equation d^2θ/dt^2= -g/L sin(θ) we find:

```
P = 4 sqrt(L/2g) ∫ (0 to θ0) dθ/sqrt[cos(θ)-cos(θ0)]

L= 1
g= 9.8
```

To simplify the value before the integral I did the following:

```
>L:=1;
>g:=9.8;
>evalf(4*sqrt(L/(2*g));
>M:=%;
```

So the integral to solve simplifies to:

```
P = M ∫ (0 to θ0) dθ/sqrt[cos(θ)-cos(θ0)]
```

When I try to evaluate the integral by itself I get the error: 
    "Error, index must evaluate to a name when indexing a module". 
I am trying to figure out how Maple wants me to enter in the integral so it will solve it.

I have tried the following as well as similar combinations of variables:

```
int(1/sqrt[cos(t)-cos(45)],t=0..45);
```

I can't conceive how to make maple solve the definite integral for me given it is cos(theta)-cos(theta0) in the denominator instead of just one variable. When I try different values for the integral I also get the following error:

```
Error, index must evaluate to a name when indexing a module
```

I must be overlooking something considerable to continue getting this error. Thanks in advance for any help or direction! :)

Comment: In Maple procedure application is done using round brackets, so your calls to `sqrt` should be like `sqrt(...)` not `sqrt[...]`. If you want a float result done with numerical quadrature then call it as `evalf(Int(...))` noting the capitalization of `Int`, or make one of the endpoints a float such as 0.0..45.00 say. Note that Maple works with radians, so perhaps you intend a range from 0.0 to `Pi/4` rather than to "45".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As acer noted in his comment, *maple* syntax doesn't use square brackets for functions. The proper syntax for your task is:

```
int(1/sqrt(cos(t)-cos(Pi/4)),t=0..Pi/4);
```

Notice that *maple* works in radians, so I replaced your `45` with `Pi/4`.

If you need a numerical value you can use `evalf`:

```
evalf(int(1/sqrt(cos(t)-cos(Pi/4)),t=0..Pi/4));
```

*maple*'s answer is `2.310196615`.

If you need to evaluate with a generic variable `theta0`, you can define a function as:

```
myint:=theta0->int(1/sqrt(cos(t)-cos(theta0)),t=0..theta0);
```

Then just call it as, e.g.,

```
myint(Pi/4);
```

and for a numerical evaluation:

```
evalf(myint(Pi/4));
```